# Regex that accepts number less than a maxium size

Tags: java, regex

Please consider this regex which accept *any numbers*. The numbers can be *comma separated* with **no more** than *4 digits*:

```
\d*\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,4})?|\.\d{1,4}
```

So all below are accepted:

```
123
12345678
123,456,789
123.000
123,456.00
1.1234
.1234
```

https://regex101.com/r/cE0uH9/1

I want that the regex also check the *total size* and **rejects** the strings which are *longer than `25`* (including comma and dot). Is it possible to do it in this regex?

Comment: That is possible however, you can also use `length` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is no longer than 25 characters:

```
^(?=.{0,25}$)
```

Combined with your regex:

```
^(?=.{0,25}$)(\d*\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,4})?|\.\d{1,4})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the length in Java before pattern matching. Checking the length is much faster than matching a regex, so you could gain some performance if you short circuit it in an `if`.